# Can I run 3 monitors off a AMD RADEON HD 6620G Graphics car on a laptop

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, external-display, hp-pavilion

I am trying to run 2 external monitors off my HP laptop Pavilion DV6 With a AMD Radeon HD 6620G Graphics card. I have one monitor going to the HDMI and one going to the VGA output but it automatically disables the 3rd screen when attempting to set up all 3. What am I missing here?

Comment: You should tell us what's the model of your laptop, your graphics card chip is kind of irrelevant. DV6 isn't specific enough. Check the bottom for the actual model number

Answer (score 0):

No it's not going to be possible. As far as I know, most laptops only allow 1 or 2 (the actual laptop screen being the 2nd) outputs. Outputting 3 or more, will require a very beefy video card with multiple outputs

It's going to be HDMI or VGA or the other.